# Derivation of Breit equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

I would like to know how one can derive from quantum electrodynamics the Breit equation i.e.

$$ i\hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = \left(\sum_i \left[ q_i\phi(\mathbf{r}_i) + c \sum_{s=x,y,z}\alpha_s(i)\pi_s(I) + \alpha_0(I)m_0c^2\right] +\sum_{i>j}\frac{1}{r_{ij}} +\sum_{i>j}\frac{1}{2r_{ij}}\left[ \mathbf{a}(i)\cdot \mathbf{a}(j) + \frac{(\mathbf{a}(i)\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij})(\mathbf{a}(j)\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij})}{r_{ij}^2}\right] \right)\Psi$$

(I'm not even sure that this is its correct form, I copied this straight from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit_equation))

Comment: It can be derived  by taking Fourier transform of the matrix element (in non-relativistic limit) of Moller scattering. The matrix element should be only corresponding to direct scattering of the electrons since nonrelativistic QM already use antisymmetric wave function. Some details are given in Sakurai's Advanced quantum mechanics.

Comment: why using antisymmetric wave functions makes the exchange term obsolete?

Comment: Non-relativistic limit of direct part takes care of exchange interaction also and hence you don't need the other part to describe anything . Incorporating it might double count or cancel the interaction altogether.